# Reference to a function call

Tags: javascript

As we can assign a function call to a new reference in javascript for example we have a function display and when we call it we use display(). And we know in javascript we can also create a reference for this for example `var call = display()`,So can i invoke this function using this  call() reference ? below is my code it is not working it is showing outerDisplay is not a function why is this happening ?

```
<script>
   var obj = {
       name: 'Saurabh',
       display: function () {
           console.log(this.name); // 'this' points to obj
       }
   };
   var outerDisplay = obj.display(); // Saurabh
   outerDisplay();
</script>
```

Comment: `()` after a function name *invokes* the function, it doesn't create another reference to it

Comment: can u please elaborate more

Comment: `obj.display();` returns `undefined` because you are calling the `display` function which then doesn't explicitly return a value (so it returns undefined by default) . so `outerDisplay` is set to `undefined` and so when you try and call it using `()` its not going to work

Comment: you can do var outerDisplay=obj.display; outerDisplay(); but at that "this" will represent window, so this.name will give you some random value.

Comment: so what is the solution for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`outerDisplay` is not a function because it already called obj.display().
However if you changed code like the below one, it won't work:

```
var outerDisplay = obj.display;
outerDisplay(); // it won't work!
```

Because it lost the "owner" of this function. You have to tell who is the owner with `call`.

```js
var obj = {
    name: 'Saurabh',
    display: function(){
        console.log(this.name); // 'this' points to obj
    }
};
var outerDisplay=obj.display; // Saurabh
outerDisplay.call(obj);
```

MDN web docs link: [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Answer (score -1):

there are 2 things which you are getting wrong.

First when you want to assign a function to a variable you should not call it.
calling a function while assigning will evaluate to the return value of your function;

so if you do

```
var outerDisplay = obj.display; // this will assign the function and you may call it as 
outerDisplay(); // will call your assigned function
```

if you do

```
var outerDisplay = obj.display(); // this will call it immediately and assign what is returned
outerDisplay(); // throw an error as outerDisplay is not a function
```

Second thing you missed;

when you assign a function to another variable then calling the variable will run in a different context.

and here `this` point to the window object;

```
window.name = "Prabhat"      
var outerDisplay = obj.display;
outerDisplay(); // print Prabhat
```